# Cassandra java process using more memory than its allocated max heap size (Xmx)

Tags: memory-management, cassandra, heap-memory

We have our cassandra cluster which runs Apache Cassandra 3.11.4 in set of unix hosts (18). each of these host has 96G of RAM and we have configured heap size to -Xms=64G -Xmx=64G but top command (top -M) on hosts shows the actual memory utilization is ~85G on average i.e. much higher than allocated heap (64G).

the trends of memory usage are like, during startup of cassandra daemon, top -M show the process has already occupied ~75G which (75G-64G)=9G more than allocated heap size, and this memory utilization increases over time and reaches to max 85G in just 3-4 hours and remains at that stage throughout the time, while the heap utilization (~40-50%) is normal, GS activities are usual, minor GC kicks in as usual.

have confirmed that the total off-heap memory utilized by all the keyspaces are below 2G on each hosts.

We are unable to trace what else is consuming the RAM in addition to the allocated heap.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the heap memory, Cassandra uses also the off-heap memory, for example for keeping compression metadata, bloom filters, and some other things.  From documentation ([1](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/operating/compression.html), [2](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/operating/bloom_filters.html)):

> Compression metadata is stored off-heap and scales with data on disk. This often requires 1-3GB of off-heap RAM per terabyte of data on disk, though the exact usage varies with chunk_length_in_kb and compression ratios.

> Bloom filters are stored in RAM, but are stored offheap, so operators should not consider bloom filters when selecting the maximum heap size.

You can monitor heap & offheap memory usage [using the JMX](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/operating/metrics.html#memory), for example. (I've seen setups, where bloom filter alone occupied ~40Gb of RAM, but it was heavily dependent on the number of the unique partition keys)

Too big heaps are usually not recommended because they can use long pauses, etc.  It of course depends on the workload, but you can try 31Gb or lower (or just use default settings).  Plus, you need to leave the memory for Linux file buffers so it will cache often used files.  That is the reason why by default Cassandra allocates only 1/4th of system memory for heap.

Comment: Thanks Alex. As mentioned we don't have terabytes of data and its just in 100GBs, hence the aggregated off-heap memory used by cassandra bloomfilter, compression metadata, memtable and index summary are small.

1/ 48G heap, GC intervals are more means more occurrences of stop-the-world.  Should it not be concerning.
2/ Similar issues reported: https://user.cassandra.apache.narkive.com/rtY3IyJx/cassandra-uses-more-memory-than-xmx and more memory than allocated heap  due to the fact of Apache Cassandra uses memory-mapped file I/O through the Unix system call mmap():